# php process 50 array elements at a time and remove them when done

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of 100 links (each array element is a link) and I want to process to 5 at a time. I was thinking of using array_slice() to achieve this however once the first 5 elements are processed I want to remove them from my array so only the unprocessed links to remain in it until all the elements are processes and array becomes empty.

My code looks like this:

```
$links = array("http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com");

$first_five = array_slice($links, 0, 5);

foreach($first_five as $ff) {
process_link($ff);
}
```

// so far so good but how do I remove the processed elements and process the remaining onces until $links[] is empty?
    ?>

Comment: Why do you want to remove the processed ones instead of just looping over every 5 elements? (Also, any reasoning behind doing 5 at a time instead of just looping over the entire array?)

Comment: looping 5 elements at a time would work too! can you give me an example ? The reason why I doing 5 at the time is because I'm using multithread curl calls to process them faster and 5 is fine for my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) might be what you're looking for. It splits the given array into an array of arrays, each containing the specified number of elements:

```
foreach (array_chunk($links, 5) as $slice) {
    // $slice is an array containing 5 elements
    // process it further
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/117383)

Comment: @JamesDean: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538).

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_splice` to remove the elements from the array and return them:

```
while (!empty($links)) {
    $first_five = array_splice($links, 0, 5);
    foreach ($first_five as $ff) {
        process_link($ff);
    }
}
```